# jump scroll though a ul of divs using the nav keys jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I've got an UL of articles (see below) they're stacked horizontally and I want to be able to scroll through them with the up/down keys so the next one becomes centred (some thing like this : http://www.thebullittagency.com . I've had a look at scrollpane but I'm unsure how to know the position of the next div to scroll to it .

So far I've got the event handler working and my articles ordered.

```
<div id="articles">
<ul>
<li>  
<article>
<a href="elements.php"><h1>Beta Site Work Begun</h1></a>

<img src="img/cross.png" name="crossbutt" width="50" height="40" id="crossbutt" />
<p id="pup">I thought I'd join in with the BBC and start work on my own beta site .      It's early days but I'm starting to get a feel for the design and which new tech I'm going   to use. The background for this first incarnation was made using Justin Windle's awesome   Super Recursion Toy and edited in PS.</p>
<h3>HTML, PHP, CSS</h3>
</article>
</li>
<li>
<article>
<a href="elements.php">
<h1>Test to test to test</h1></a>
<img src="img/cross.png" width="50" height="40" id="crossbutt" />
<p id="pup">Test the test to test the test compare .</p>
<h3>HTML, PHP, CSS</h3>
</article>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position: absolute` for your main div and control that position based on keypresses, like so: ([Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/cAhga/))

---

### css

```
#articles {
    position: absolute;
}

/* Optional: Hide scrollbar */
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### js

```
var current = current = $('#articles ul li').first();

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 40) { // down
        current = current.next().length === 0 ? current : current.next();
    } else if (e.which === 38) { // up
        current = current.prev().length === 0 ? current : current.prev();
    } else {
        return;
    }
    if (!current || current.length === 0) {
        current = $('#articles ul li').first();
    }
    console.log(current.position());
    $('#articles').animate({
        top: '-' + current.position()['top'] + 'px'
    }, 150);
});
```

Comment: cheers , sort of works but the placement is dead centre of the screen . Is there a way of doing it without the position absolute ?

Comment: I would probably use anchors for each article and use [`jQuery.scrollTo`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) instead. This way you get bookmarkability and the scrollbar still functions as expected. I may provide this as an alternative solution later.

Comment: if you could that'd be great . Could you give a brief explaination of the code , I'm still learning and it would really help . thanks

Comment: could you let me know if your going to do the scrollTo code , if not I'll pop another question up . thx